# forcing overflow-x using percentage and float

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow, percentage

I have a small structure of `<li>` inside a container and what i'm trying to make is to force the `overflow-x` appear instead of `overflow-y`, but i can't achieve this, i presume it is beacuse of properties `float` and the percentage that i'm using.

is there i way where i can reach this result ? show only the horizontal overflow ?

here is the code:

**html**

```
 <div id="CockpitCenter">
    <ul class="CockpitContainerResult">
      <li><div class="box">Box 1</div></li>
      <li><div class="box">Box 2</div></li>
      <li><div class="box">Box 3</div></li>
      <li  style="height: 400px;">
          <div class="box" style="height: 370px;">Box 4</div>
      </li>
      <li><div class="box">Box 5</div></li>
      <li><div class="box">Box 6</div></li>
      <li><div class="box">Box 7</div></li>
   </ul>
 </div>​
```

and **css**

```
#CockpitCenter {
   height: 500px; /* set only here in jsFiddle */
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   border: solid 2px #ccc;
   border-bottom: none;
   overflow: auto;
}

div#CockpitCenter ul.CockpitContainerResult {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}

ul.CockpitContainerResult li {
   margin: 5px 0;
   height: 150px;
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
}

ul.CockpitContainerResult li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}

ul.CockpitContainerResult li div.box {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ybJ6C/7/)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? I'm having trouble understanding. You're never going to get an `overflow-x` to appear because those elements will never span greater than the parent element based on your CSS.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: yes, this is the problem, is there a way to reach a solution where my `overflow-x`will appear ? If you say that i need to change the sctructure, be my guest saying it, accept any tips. :)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: imagine that my container will only accept 4 box's , more then that, `overflow-x` appear.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to make a carousel, which there are many handy jquery plugins for. Regardless, you cannot do this using percentages for widths, you have to give your main container a fixed width, then give the inner one (your ul) whatever larger width you want. You must force a width on the UL otherwise the LI elements will just wrap. Once thats done just add an 'overflow-x: auto' to the main container and you should be on your way.

Quick example, http://jsfiddle.net/ybJ6C/8/

I'm using my ipad right now, and didn't see the scroll bar but it does indeed scroll. You'll notice that the scroll continues well past the end, you can adjust that with the width if you know what you want. If its dynamic then you would need js to adjust the width for you based on the elements within. I also don't have the height correct, but its enough to get the idea. (again doing this from my ipad, coding ain't the greatest)